# URLConnection Delegate methods are not getting called

Tags: objective-c

I am using two web services in my code.
and calling methods on tap of alert button 
My Code is

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {
  if(buttonIndex==1)
  {
  if(alertView==AlertDel)
  {

  ```
  [self DeleteFromServerDatabase];
  ```

  }
  }
  }
  -(void)DeleteFromServerDatabase
  {[loading setFrame:CGRectMake(140, 210, 40, 40)];
  [loading setHidden:NO];
  [loader setHidden:NO];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:loader];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:loading];
  [loading startAnimating];
  NSString *devToken=app.iDevice;
  //  NSString *devToken= [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
  if(devToken)
  {

  }
  else 
      devToken=@"c677";
      NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"\n"
                               "\n"
                               "\n"
                               "\n"
                               "%@\n"
                               "%@\n"
                               "%@\n"
                               "\n"
                               "\n"
                               "\n",bday.fname,bday.lname,devToken
                               ];

  ```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://72.167.96.135:8101/BirthDayWebService.asmx"];
  NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

  [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/DeleteBirthday" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
  [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  theConnection2 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

  if( theConnection2 )
  {
      webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  }
  else
  {

  }
  ```

  }
  but any of UrlConnection delegates are not getting called.
  Please help me out of this

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything in your else clause:

```
if( theConnection2 )
{
  webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{

}
```

Are you sure that the connection was was properly initialized? The `NSURLConnection` docs say:

> **Return Value**
>
> The URL connection for the URL request. Returns `nil` if a connection can't be initialized.

Also, make sure that you start the load on the main thread or whatever thread you want to be called back on:

> Messages to the delegate will be sent on the thread that calls this method.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot `[theConnection2 start]`